# Delete a DrawingManager shape when drawing a new one

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drawing

I created a custom toggle to init the DrawingManager, and I'm able to delete the current shape (if there is one) when I initialise it using `currentShape.setMap(null)`.

But how to delete a shape created with the DrawingManager at the precise moment the user starts do draw a new one?

As far as I know there's no "drawingstart" event (not in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManagerOptions)), for example, that could fire at the moment when the user starts drawing a shape.

I tried using this...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function(e) {
  if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() == "circle"){
    currentShape.setMap(null);
  }
});
```

...and also using the 'click' event, but those events don't fire when `drawingManager.getDrawingMode() == "circle"`.

```
function initMap(){

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  $toggleDrawing.on('click', function(){      
    toggleDrawing();
  });

}

function toggleDrawing(){

  if (!isDrawing){
    if (!selectedArea){

      // enable drawing mode
      isDrawing = true;
      $toggleDrawing.addClass('active');
      initDrawing();
    }else{

      // delete selected area
      deleteSelectedArea();
    }
  }else{

    // disable drawing mode after drawing a shape
    isDrawing = false;
    $toggleDrawing.removeClass('active');
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  }
}

function initDrawing(){
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    drawingControl: false
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    selectedArea = e.overlay;
    toggleDrawing(false); // will set to false
  });

  // 'click' or 'dragstart' event are not fired if `drawingManager.getDrawingMode() == "circle"` (or any other shape)

  // google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
  //   if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() == "circle"){
  //     selectedArea.setMap(null);
  //   }
  // });

  // google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function(e) {
  //   if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() == "circle"){
  //     selectedArea.setMap(null);
  //   }
  // });
}

function deleteSelectedArea() {
  if (selectedArea) {
    selectedArea.setMap(null);
    selectedArea = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I think the best you are going to do is to remove any existing shapes when use the tool bar to get into edit mode.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of how it's working now: by pressing the toggle it deletes the shape (if any) and on the next toggle it gets into edit mode, and out of edit mode if toggle is pressed again, or if a shape is created. But I couldn't find a way to delete the existing shape only when it starts drawing another. I just updated with the code.

Comment: The only enhancement to that I could suggest would be to delete the shapes when you get into edit mode, not when you exit edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Too easy. Attach event to the map-canvas instead of map:

```
// If it's drawing mode, delete the selected area (if there is one)
$('#map-canvas').on('click', function() {
  if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() == "circle"){
    deleteSelectedArea();
  }
});
```

Nice tips [here](http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/06/using-google-maps-drawing-manager-to_30.html).